# Why is this option strategy's lower bound $50?

Tags: options

[image]

Why is the payoff 0 when the price drops under 50? When we sell the short call, we get $60 and we need to cover our position so if the price drops to let's say $40. We don't need to execute the option but don't we need to buy the stock at $40 from the market and return the underlying security? And therefore, we still gain 60-40=20?

I am new to this concept so I am sorry if the answer seems very obvious.

Comment: "when we sell the short call, we get $60". Why? I don't see the premium mentioned on those charts anywhere.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/short-call.asp I checked this website and it says "Selling the call option allows Liquid to collect a premium upfront; that is, Paper pays liquid $11,000 (100 x $110)" So I assume in this case we get 60 x 1 = $60. And I think the graph ignores the premium for explanation sake

Comment: It does, which is why I'm wondering where you got the impression that the premium is $60.

Comment: @John - Investopedia offers a lot of really good information about the financial markets.  However occasionally, they get it spectacularly wrong.  The article in your link is garbage.  Not only is the math wrong but so is the concept about how short calls work.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that! Do you know articles that are well written about how short calls work?

Comment: https://hedgetrade.com/what-is-a-short-call/ 
this one is correct?

Comment: The articles is fine until the point wherre it gets to: EXAMPLES OF THESE CALLS.  Then, it falls apart.

Comment: Could you provide the link to this YouTube video?

Answer (score 1):

$50 and $60 are the strike prices of the calls.

The graphs in each picture are correct in that they depict the nature of the P&L curve for each strategy.  However, they are deficient because the numbers on the X axis have no relevance to anything. You cannot have a P&L curve if you don't know either the respective  premiums or the net premium.  Here's an example:

XYZ = $56.00

Jun $50c = $6.50

Jun $60c = $1.00

Buying this bullish call spread costs $5.50.  On an expiration basis:

- Break even is $55.50
- Maximum profit is $4.50 at or above $60.00
- Maximum loss is $5.50 at or below $50.00

Comment: This is so much clearer. Thank you. Do you know if there are any articles with good explanations on short-selling calls? since I can't distinguish the good articles and bad articles with my current level of knowledge. thank you!

Comment: "I can't distinguish the good articles and bad articles with my current level of knowledge." That's the problem with the internet.  There's a lot of junk out there and they  will sidetrack your learning curve. A better suggestion would be to pick up a copy of "Options As A Strategic Investment" by McMillan. You don't need the current, most expensive edition.  Pick up an older copy for peanuts and years from now, if you move on to more advanced strategies, pick up the latest edition.  It's well written and easy to understand.

Comment: the maximum profit is $4.50 at or above $60 because the person that we sell the call for will exercise the option so we get 60-55.5
However, when the price is below 60, would the call buyer just choose not to execute the $60 option? and we still lose $5.5 since we already buy the $50 call.

Comment: I meant not exercising the $60 call and the buyer of the call can just purchase from the market.

Comment: Above $60, if  the owner exercises his $60 then you will  sell the stock for $60.  You then exercise your long call to buy the stock for $50 for a  $10 gain.  Since your spread cost you $5.50, you realize a gain of $4.50.  If you wish to reduce the chance of exercise, when the short $60 call no longer has time premium in it, close it.

Comment: Let's say I sell the $60 call to B. When the stock drops below $60, B decides not to exercise the call. Therefore, I don't have to return the stock to B. But I still can exercise my $50 call option and sell it to the market? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: If B exercises his call, you would have to deliver (not return) shares to him.  You would not exercise your call (1) and sell to the market unless you covered the short call and (2) it's better to close the options rather than exercise them and then have to close the equity position because it involves fewer transactions and less slippage (unless your goal is to acquire the stock for ownership).

Comment: well if the market price is $56, why don't we exercise the $50 call to get the stock and sell it in the market? because at the price of $56 B wouldn't exercise the call, he would just buy it from the market right? and if the price is 56 we can exercise the call and sell it to the market and have a 56-55.5=0.5 realized gain?

Comment: First, see point (2) in my previous comment.  What happens if one minute after you exercise your $50  call and sell the stock that there is good news and the price of XYZ zooms past $60. You now have a naked $60 call with boundless upside risk.   B exercises it and rut-roh.

Comment: so if the stock goes below 60 just a moment before the option expires then we can do the transaction I mentioned? or does that not work in the real world because we can't be sure about the rapid price movement between the timing of exercise and the expiration of the option?

Comment: You can do whatever you want but the risk is not gone until the options expire.  Read this article which explains [when options expire](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/expiration-time.asp)